# Can field itself have a speed?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, electric-fields, field-theory, speed

I've seen many examples about a particle moving relative to field.

But I never saw a field moving relative to observer (or a particle).

So, can field have a speed?

I thought about some possibilities:

1. Field is just a theoretical concept, so it doesn't exist and cannot have a speed.
2. A speed of field is same as wave on the field.
3. Field can have speed, as particles can.

First one seems wrong, because there are 'existing' waves on field, like EM wave.

Second one seems make sense, but I thought wave is just a change on a field. Does it right?

Third one is most weird case. If field itself can have a speed, then it should be 0 to every observer.

For EM field, if observer see it while moving, it just change its value according to Lorentz transformation. EM wave moves relative to EM field, and it has speed value of $c$.

So, which one is right? (or all of them are wrong?) Can anyone explain this, or give some source to learn about it?

This question bothers me after I learned special relativity, and didn't solved until now, learning QFT.

Comment: May be it can help imagining the field as excitations of a media (which becomes more accurate in condensed physics). In that analogy,  the question itself doesn't really have much sense. Thus, whatever a quantum field is, it likely doesn't make sense  trying to think of it having "speed" as a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll briefly address these possibilities you layed out.

1. A field is every bit as real as a particle. Or you could say that a particle is every bit as "theoretical" as a field. In fact, quantum field theory (QFT) teaches us that particles can be seen as nothing more than certain excited states of fields. In QFT we talk about fields and particles as if they are the same thing (for instance people say "electron" and this can mean either an electron particle, or the electron field, they are treated as one and the same, although most would say the fields are more fundamental). It's a bit hard to wrap your mind around why particles and fields are the same but they are.
2. Yes, waves on a field can have speed, but that's not really the same thing as the "speed" of a field. However, remember how particles are fields? Well, a photon corresponds to the electromagnetic field, and the speed of light is the speed of electromagnetic waves, which is the same as the speed of photons, for instance. So this is probably as close as you will get to having a speed that is as similar as possible as the particle case.
3. Not quite, but something related. A field is everywhere in space, so you can't say that it has a speed in the same sense a particle does (that means, how far it moves within a unit of time). It can have a related property, which is momentum. Momentum in basic physics for particles is just mass times velocity.  With fields, it is something more abstract, and it doesn't necessarily need to correspond to some speed.

The easiest way to think about it is probably the field being able to transfer momentum from one body to the other. In fact, in many cases it looks like Newton's third law is violated. The third law says that for every action there is an equal but opposite reaction. So the sum of all the forces should be zero. But sometimes you have an interaction between two bodies and you find out that the sum of forces on them is not zero. The very simple reason is that force is better thought of as the rate of change of momentum, and there is some momentum "hidden" in the field that you did not account for. In electromagnetism, this hidden momentum often manifests as radiation, you know, light. Note that the basic formula p=mv for momentum does not apply here, the field has no mass, but it has momentum.

So a field can have momentum, which is... Kinda like speed. Kinda. It's not the same and even though you can calculate the momentum (or rather momentum density) of an electromagnetic field, you can't infer from that some velocity, it's not well defined. But it's an interesting concept.